# Write npgsqlexception string to file does not write

Tags: c#, file-io, exception

Hello I am trying to put npgsqlexception string into text file but somehow it does not write to it but string shows in console window, Log.txt file exists in debug folder. Here is the code:

```
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
   StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("\\Log.txt");
   file.WriteLine(ex);
   file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried providing the full path to the log file?

Comment: Remove both backslashes.

Comment: Tryed to remove both of them, but file is still empty console full of exceptions. I need only app directory becouse program will be used on many PC

Comment: @Bensinaspa what do you mean Console is full of exceptions. also when writing to a file you need a valid `FilePath` for example look at the `StreamWriter` overloads something like this 
`StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);` also the file is created in the `Debug` folder when you remove the `"\\"`

Comment: @Bensinaspa people will downvote this if they so choose however.. what is the ultimate problem. you want to write a file to the `App` folder.. correct..? then what is the file path to that folder..? if you run this code is the exception block even being hit.. did you debug this and put breakpoints..? can you post all of your relevant code..?

Comment: I don't want to use file path, becouse other people will have different paths. @Farhan Anam updated solution helped.

Comment: I wouldn't use the application's folder. What if user doesn't have permissions? Use the "App Data" folder instead. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `StreamWriter.Flush()` to write the data to the file:

```
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
   StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("Log.txt");
   file.WriteLine(ex);
   file.Flush();
   file.Close();
}
```

**Update** - Remove the backslashes as well. If it still didn't work, try using a FileStream as in the StreamWriter constructor:

```
 StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
```

**Update** - If it still doen't work, there's got to some other problem. The above should definitely work. As an alternative, you can use:

```
File.WriteAllText("Log.txt", ex.ToString());
```

Comment: Does not help, file is not even created.

Comment: @FarhanAnam so you're going to `call file.Close()` before `file.Flush()` this is not the answer. Also if he wants the file to be created in the App directory then he needs to use the StreamWriter overload to pass the file path, true || false, in order to overwrite the file if it exist or not.. the flush is not even needed for the simple writing to the file in the exception block, I could see if you were in a loop and wanting to view what has been written etc...flushing is good ..but for this it's not really necessary

Comment: `StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));` still not necessary

Comment: @MethodMan Yes you are right. `StreamWriter.Close()` also writes the data to the file. Everything seems to work for me yet not for the OP! How strange is that?

Comment: the OP doesn't understand that the file is created in the `bin` directory meaning the location of where the file is executed that is where the file will be created.. the OP will need to specify a file path to the App folder + the filename what I have posted in the comment is all that he needs plus the closing of the StreamWriter variable after the logging of the exception 
`StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(@filePath + \ + Log.txt , true);`

Comment: @MethodMan Even when you specify just the filename like "file.txt", the file is (usually) created in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(ex.ToString());` still not necessary if that's the case why not just you are confusing such a simple task
`StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(@filePath + Log.txt , true);
fileStream.WriteLine(ex.Message);`

Comment: @MethodMan Then why don't you post your 'UltraSimple' way of accomplishing this task as an answer?

Comment: this also takes 2 params not one `File.WriteAllText(ex.ToString());`

Comment: @MethodMan Yes that's one good thing you've pointed out in a while.

Comment: everything I've pointed out is good need i refresh your memory on all the edits that you have done since I've corrected your code..? anyway.. the OP needs to show all the code.. perhaps the exception block is not even being hit at all..

Comment: @MethodMan I appreciate the fact that you have helped improved this question. I am sorry but I got angry when you said I was confusing a simple task.